# What's the state of the art for computing the largest singular value of a matrix

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

My matrix is not sparse, and is sized 30k by 30k.  Most importantly, the gap between the largest and the second largest singular values is small or even 0.

ARPACK, SLEPc, Matlab, PROPACK?  Which one is more stable and fast?  Many thanks.